# Centralizing buttons on the navbar

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html, css, navbar

I have the following buttons on my navbar:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" >

    <div class="btn-group ex" data-toggle="buttons" style="vertical-align:middle">
        <label class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">
            <input type="radio" name="options" id="blocos" value="blocos"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span>
        </label>
        <label class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">
            <input type="radio" name="options" id="lista" value="lista"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-justify"></span>
        </label>
    </div>
    <a class="btn btn-success btn-sm" id="infopopover" rel="popover" data-style="primary"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>
    <input type="hidden" id="modoexibicao" />
    <input type="hidden" id="contratocod" />

    @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")

</ul>
```

They are shown as follows:

[image]

I would like them to stay aligned in the center of the navbar . What to do ?

Comment: An **ul** element is meant to contain **li** elements. May be better change it to a **div**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked with the following css code:

```
.navbar-nav {
      height:50px; 
      display:flex; 
      align-items:center;
}
```

And the ***vertical-align:middle*** 
in the second div style:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

    <div class="btn-group ex" data-toggle="buttons" style="vertical-align:middle">
        <label class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">
            <input type="radio" name="options" id="blocos" value="blocos"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span>
        </label>
        <label class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">
            <input type="radio" name="options" id="lista" value="lista"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-justify"></span>
        </label>
    </div>
    <a class="btn btn-success btn-sm" id="infopopover" rel="popover" data-style="primary"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>
    <input type="hidden" id="modoexibicao" />
    <input type="hidden" id="contratocod" />

    @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")

</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your stylesheet add:

```
ul{
    text-align: center;
}
```

or add 'text-align:center' to one of the other applicable classes in your ul element if you don't want any other ul's referenced by this style.